# Data got into Mysterious Folder

Tags: windows-xp

I was installing .Net framework on an xp machine, which created a mysterious folder on my D: drive, (name was some 20 characters long, and it was a hexadecimal kind of name)
that folder was accessible, but the data inside was inaccessible

by mistake i dragged an important folder inside that folder ( cut & pasted inside that folder) and now my folder is present there but the data inside that folder isn't accessible

Is there any was out to get that folder / data back?

should I delete it using some kind of software (unlocker) and then try to recover it?

Comment: If you delete the folder then the file you want will be deleted. Just take ownership of the folder.  The downvote is because I was forced to provide a link on how to take ownership of a folder. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder on your D: drive is a typical side-effect of installing certain types of updates and patches.  You have to take ownership of the folder first, then you can have full rights to what's in it.  This assumes that you are a system administrator;  if you're not, you can't do it.

- Right-click on the folder, choose Properties > Security
- Click the Advanced button, click the Owner tab, click the Edit button to change ownership
- Highlight your name in "change ownership" and checkmark the box for "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects". Click Apply.

  Now you can fully access the folder, read files in it, delete it,
  etc.